# Linear mappings between two modules as a commutative ring (claim in Bourbaki)

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

In Bourbaki, Algebra I, Chapter II, paragraph 1.2 (p. 195), it is claimed that the set $Hom_A(E,F)$ of linear mappings between two $A$-modules is a *commutative* ring. How would the ring operations be defined on $Hom_A(E,F)$ to make it into a commutative ring?

[image]

Comment: Try obvious ones such as $(f + g )(r) = f(r) + g(r)$ and $(fg)(r) = f(r)g(r)$ and see if they work.

Comment: Based on the remarks that follow, it's possible they meant to write "commutative group", but I'm not aware of an errata list to confirm.

Comment: @blargoner Good point, thank you. That could be it.

Comment: I had a thought this morning that it would be good to look at the original French, but I don't have a copy.